# Formatting Data for use in SKmultilearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, data-formats

I have a dataframe of X values and one with the y values in what I think is the proper format. I took the single feature y and converted it to dummies so it's binary and is m rows by n features.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df.drop('target',axis=1)
y = pd.get_dummies(df['target'], sparse=True, drop_first=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=99, train_size=0.60
```

I've been trying to figure out how exactly the data should look from the [documentation](http://scikit.ml/api/datasets.html) but am not having much luck.

I first tried the following:

```
import skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

classifier = BinaryRelevance(GaussianNB())
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

where X, y train sets are pandas dataframes. This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: no suppoerted conversion for types: (dytype('O'),)
```

Then I converted to matrices:

```
X_train = X_train.asmatrix()
y_train = y_train.asmatrix()
```

I received the same error. Then I tried

```
X_train = np.matrix(X_train)
y_train = np.matrix(y_train)
```

Same error again. Is there an easy way to go from dataframe to proper format for skmultilearn models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the features were categorical, so they had to be converted to integers.

Then, I ran this to get the data in the right format:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
X_train = sp.csr_matrix(X_train)
y_train = sp.csr_matrix(y_train)
```